# IOS: FQL Statement, no results

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get the name of the pages, where user is the admin. but there aren't any results. I use below code,

```
 NSString *query =
             @"SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id IN "
             @"(SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me())";
             // Set up the query parameter
             NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
             // Make the API request that uses FQL
             [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                          parameters:queryParam
                                          HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                                   completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                       id result,
                                                       NSError *error) {
                                       if (error) {
                                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                       } else {
                                           NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                                       }
                                   }];
```

Any help?

Comment: Your code is correct check your query.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the query? I didn't get it

Comment: Did you try another FQL query for same code?

Comment: Yes and It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Graph_API. Steps-

get "manage_pages" permission from User (extended permissions)

call graph API- https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts

U can test this procedure [in this page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/accounts) -> Just click on 'Get Access Token' button-> under 'Extended permission' check 'manage_pages' & submit it. It will give you the admin-page-details JSON.

Try and let me know.Thank you.

Comment: Thank you,
Can you tell me how to make the graph API request from the code? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Just try this query in your code - 'SELECT page_id,page_url,name,pic_square FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me())'

Comment: It's the same, No results. Do I need to get "manage_pages" permissions for the user? I don't know how to do it inside the app.

Comment: Then check is there any pages created by logged in user. because above query is works perfectly for me.

Comment: Yes,logged user have the pages. Can you tell me how to call the graph API inside the app?

Comment: "U can test this procedure in this page -> Just click on 'Get Access Token' button-> under 'Extended permission' check 'manage_pages' & submit it". After doing this I got the results. How can I get manage_pages permission through my app, for every user?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41689/discussion-between-chanuka-and-smita)